# pods issue, linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

when I run my project, I get errors like this:
[image]

It seems that all frameworks in my cocoapods have problem. Is it my problem of my cocoapods? I have reinstalled my cocoapods, and used 'pod setup' or 'pod install' and others, but it doesn't work, and I still have the same errors...
And in Xcode, red 'rd' on the 'Podfile' like this, I don't know if it is related to errors.
[image]

pod 1.0.0
ruby 2.0.0
xcode 7.3.1
Anyone have the same problem?

Comment: maybe clean derived data section of your xcode ?

Comment: something else: I can run other projects which depend on cocoapods, but my team's projects have this problem.My team's projects use my own Private Pods.This has influence on my problem? But I remove private pods from Podfile,it still have same errors...

Comment: you can try to de-integrate Pod and try to integrate it later. Here is de-integrate script: https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate

Comment: @Shubhank It doesn't work, even I reinstall my OS ..

Comment: This solved it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52232100/invalid-bitcode-version-producer-902-0-39-2-0-reader-900-0-37-0

Comment: In my case this was an issue with the latest Toolchain I installed, I switched back to Xcode 10 toolchain (default) everything went back to normal and error went away

Answer (score 39):

This worked for me:

```
pod deintegrate 
pod install
```

Comment: this is the only solution that worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 37):

I faced similar problem in my project. After hours of searching I found that in GENERAL settings of the project in section "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" there are two files for pods: `"libPods.a"` and `"Pods_ProjectName.framework`"

Deleting `"libPods.a"` helped in my case.

[image: Linked Frameworks and Libraries]

Comment: just want to say thank you, this was my issue. I had yarn removed a library but i still needed to remove it from this linked frameworks tab :)

Comment: @Bastek Actually taking a out for Unity.Where to find the settings? I cant find. Using Xcode 10

Comment: @zyonneo select your project file in the left pane, you should see settings

Comment: @Bastek What do you mean by settings? Is it folder view similar to the image added by the the person who asked this question.I have the exact same view and I cant find the Pod folder

Comment: @zyonneo I mean general project settings. In the question example I mean click on the "Pacs" project file on top, there you should see all settings.

Comment: @Bastek I found out the Linke Frameworks and Librabries but no luck.There is 
 no libPods.a or Pods_Sport.framework

Comment: @Bastek Pls have a look...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51629954/how-to-solve-an-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-inv

Answer (score 10):

Actually issue is related to dependency management for xcode project. You can refer below answer link for solving "linker issue" in xcode. That worked for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38371271/6827175

Comment: Please post relevant sections of the answer here itself as links might change over time.

Answer (score 8):

There are can be a few different cases;

Also, it would help to know all information from your print screen :)

Have you tried to clean your delivery data ?

1. Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Open "Location Menu" -> Open Folder With DeliveryData
2. Close your XCode;(even go to "Force Quit.." menu and close XCode there);
3. Clean trash bin;
4. And try build again.

Second case:

1. Open your target -> Build Settings -> Build Active Architecture
   Only->  set "No" option
2. Do the same with all
   your pods' target

Answer (score 6):

Try to deleting Podfile.lock file and Pods folder. Then try to pods install.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I spent 2 days to find the real culprit. It turns out that I tried to run the "Project" instead of running the "Workspace". How this will help others!

Answer (score 2):

I changed `Deployment target` from 10.0 to 11.0, and this work !

[image]

Comment: I had this issue. In my case it was a react-native app added Firebase Analytics. As of July 2018, all apps must be built with iOS 11 per Apple:  developer.apple.com/ios/submit/

Once I went to my General tab and scrolled down to Deployment Info / Deployment Target and changed it from 10.x which is what I was targeting, to 11.x - the app built/archived and I was able to submit.

Comment: Literally spent my whole weekend banging my head over this issue. This worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to check your Xcode version and than check pod version which you installed. If your Xcode version under 9.0 then you should reinstall pod with but old version not latest. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I plugged out my real device but in the simulator still it looks Generic iOS device. So I changed it with some simulator and it is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

in my case i changed run simulator to iphone x with ios 11.4 , then it compailed and run OK , then i run in iphone 4s with ios 9.3 , and it wont got error

i think probably issue is in ui test and unit testing components , i hope that apple fix them

Comment: Interestingly it runs in simulator just fine but when trying to run on my iPhone I get the error anyways..

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in test project just make sure that the project has valid **`host application`** [image]

Answer (score 0):

Same issues here. I had not made any changes other than adding some icons to the project. After a few hours of clicking around, I clicked on the pods project and changed the search path to Yes. That solved it for me. [image: Screen shot of Xcode]

Answer (score 0):

This happened to my project because I used Admob in my Unity project and then build it for iOS. I did not note that `Unity-iPhone.xcworkspace` is created to open instead of `Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj`. I was keep opening `Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj` and it was giving the error. Opening the project with `Unity-iPhone.xcworkspace` fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Workspace Setting and change Build System to Legacy Build System worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you selected Legacy Build System so change that because this has deprecated
from xcode so use
pod deintegrate
pod install

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Fix** worked for me

1. `File -> New -> File`

[image]

2. Create a `swift` file

[image]

3. Confirm `Create Bridging Header`
   [image]
4. Go to `Build Settings` and set `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` to `YES`
   [image]
5. `pod deintegrate`
6. `pod install`

Answer from [AlVelig answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52536380/why-linker-link-static-libraries-with-errors-ios/54586937#54586937)